# Store of value to raw pointer in C going to the wrong address

Tags: c, embedded, arm64, bare-metal

I have the following exit code in C:

```
void _exit(int status) {
   extern long long uart_addr asm ("__uart__");
   int* uart = uart_addr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   *uart = 1;
}
```

And I’ve compiled it with `aarch64-none-elf-gcc`.

However, I’m seeing this as a result in the assembly:

```
void _exit(int status) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   extern long long uart_addr asm ("__uart__");
   int* uart = uart_addr;
   *uart = 1;
     80002660: d0d7ffe0  adrp  x0, 30000000 <Image$$UART$$Base>
     80002664: 52800021  mov w1, #0x1                    // #1
     80002668: f9400000  ldr x0, [x0]
     8000266c: b9000001  str w1, [x0]
```

My question is: why does 0x80002668 exist? I’m taking the value at `__uart__` (0x3000_0000) and assigning that value `long long uart_addr` to a pointer `int* uart`. Then I’m writing 1 to the memory that pointer is pointing to `*uart = 1`.

What happens with the assembly code above is that the pointer (x0) gets overwritten by the LDR at 0x80002668 (`ldr x0, [x0]`) and the store of value 1 goes towards a completely different address.

This is a bare metal program and 0x3000_0000 is my UART.

Comment: You declare `uart_addr` to have type `char`.  This is not wide enough to hold an address.  It's unclear to me whether you want to assign its *address* to `uart`, or whether you maybe want to just skip it, and assign the same value directly to `uart`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to assign the value (0x3000_0000) which is the value of __uart__ to uart_addr. You're totally right that I shouldn't declare it as char. My bad.

Comment: Still, the problem persists. I don't understand why the compiler inserted a LDR instruction there.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've fixed the question content.

Comment: Since you are apparently trying to access a HW register, the register should be flagged as volatile. So your uart pointer should be a pointer to volatile. I don't see why the line you are worried about is there, but it doesn't have any observable affect - for a plain variable. It is an oddity. If uart were a pointer to volatile, then inserting an extra read, even though its result is thrown away, would be a code generation error - not just an oddity. Aside: wouldn't it make more sense for uart_addr to be an actual pointer type?

Comment: @AviBerger the extra LDR isn't an oddity though. It replaces the value of x0 (the value of the pointer address) and modifies the program behavior. I can try declaring the pointer as volatile but I don't think that explains the behavior here....

Comment: Sorry, I was remembering the previous version of the code which showed a load to w0, not x0. Note: pointer to volatile, not volatile pointer and that should be done for memory mapped HW registers regardless of your issue here.

Comment: OK, I just looked up the specifics for your asm line. Apparently that aliases the variable to an asm variable named __uart__ and are presumably locating at address 0x3000_0000 via assembly/linker specifications. That explains the issue. Your code isn't what you think it is. Your code should be more like: `extern volatile uint8_t uart_addr asm ("__uart__");     uart = 1;` (replacing uint8_t appropriately if the register is a different size.)

Comment: @AviBerger Thanks but I'm not sure why my code doesn't work. ```uart_addr``` should have the value 0x3000_0000 (value of ```__uart__``` in the linker). And assigning that value to a pointer ```int* uart = uart_addr``` should work right? If not, could you please explain why?

Comment: The more standard way to do this is to use preprocessor macros like `#define UART_DR ((volatile unsigned char *)0x3000)` and then `UART_DR = 1;`.  You can also use a struct to represent the UART and all its registers.  No need for assembly.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Right but that means the address isn't determined by the linker. I want the address to pick up whatever the linker sets UART to.

Comment: This is a for HW register. Whichever way you do it, you (or the board support package) have to specify the correct address. This can be done a number of different ways, depending on the tool chain. The linker doesn't figure it out on its own, it gets told.

Comment: Right but I want whatever the linker to get told to be what the code interpretes. Without having to change the code. If that makes sense.

Comment: The correct type to use would be `uintptr_t`. Likely equivalent to `unsigned long long` on your system.

Comment: Since the linker symbol `__uart__` has a value (doesn't have an address, but is an address) have you considered doing it this way:  `void _exit(int status) { extern uintptr_t __uart__[]; volatile int32_t *uart = (volatile int32_t *)__uart__; *uart = 1; }` . If the uart port is 8 bit (byte) then replace `int32_t *` with `int8_t *`

Comment: Of course I'm using the types from `inttypes.h` in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

What your current posted code does:

`extern long long uart_addr asm ("__uart__");`

Map C variable uart_addr to asm variable __ uart __. Not shown, but this asm variable is mapped to address 0x3000_0000. Location in memory, not the value of the contents. There is no indication whether the value at that address (of that variable) is ever initialized.

`int* uart = uart_addr;`

Fetch the (possibly uninitialized) value from 0x3000_0000 and use it to initialize the pointer variable uart. If that memory location didn't have a valid content, this will effectively set the pointer variable uart to an unusable/incorrect value.

`*uart = 1;`

Set memory at the address now contained in pointer variable uart to the value 1. This is **not** a write to 0x3000_0000, but the address that was read from that location. *Your mystery line of assembly code is fetching that address from address 0x3000_0000.*

What I think you wanted: (assuming it is an 8 bit uart register, needs adjustment if not)

```
void _exit(int status) {
  extern volatile uint8_t uart asm ("__uart__");     
  uart = 1;
}
```